# Embed contents of source file inside source block in an org mode document (latex)

Tags: emacs, export, org-mode

In pseudo-code I'd like to do the following in my org-mode file:

```
#+BEGIN_src python
[[./a_python_script_whose_contents_i_want_in_my_document.py]]
#+END_src
```

i.e. have the entire contents of a separate file be embedded in my org-mode document when I export it to latex.

How do I embed the contents of a separate file within an org-mode document, and have that content be formatted as source code when exporting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that in org-mode with a source block that I know of. This will give you what you want if you have minted setup:

```
\inputminted{python}{your-script.py}
```

or if you use lsting

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{source_filename.py}
```